# How to pass in a string into dynamic sql inside a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, validation, stored-procedures

As of now I have a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT 
    y.ID, y.STATUS, y.CONTROLID, y.TRCDE
FROM 
    YTDTRNI AS y 
LEFT JOIN 
    VND AS v ON y.COMNO = v.COMNO 
WHERE 
    TRCDE ='RC' 
ORDER BY 
    ID DESC
```

I am trying to use this query inside a stored procedure using dynamic SQL. So far, my stored procedure looks like this:

```
SET @query =  N'SELECT y.ID, y.STATUS, y.CONTROLID, y.TRCDE
                FROM YTDTRNI AS y LEFT JOIN VND AS v ON y.COMNO = v.COMNO 
                WHERE TRCDE = ' + @searchtrtype + ' 
                ORDER BY ' + @orderbycondition
```

The variables `@searchtrtype` and `@orderbycondition` are of type `nvarchar`.

I am using a ASP.NET/C# program to call the stored procedure. However, it breaks with an exception:

> An expression of non boolean type in a context where a condition is expected near 'ORDER'

I think I am getting error because the string values are not properly concatenated or formatted in inside the `@query` variable.

Open to any advice.

EDIT: my stored procedure looks like this at the moment:

[image]

When I execute the stored procedure, it returns the result set that I want but it also shows an error message :

> Must declare the scalar variable "@dsearchtrtype".

I tried declaring it inside the `BEGIN` body and declaring it as part of a parameter for the stored procedure but it still shows that same message.

Comment: have you got missing apostrophes?

Comment: Could you show the variable declaration? or the full stored proc code?

Comment: Be careful with SQL injection

Answer (score 4):

Learn to use parameters with `sp_executesql`.  You can do this for `@searchtrtype`, but not `@orderbycondition`:

```
SET @query =  N'
SELECT y.ID, y.STATUS,y.CONTROLID,y.TRCDE
FROM YTDTRNI y LEFT JOIN
     VND v
     ON y.COMNO = v.COMNO 
WHERE TRCDE = @searchtrtype 
ORDER BY @orderbycondition';

SET @query = REPLACE(@query, '@orderbycondition', @orderbycondition);

EXEC sp_executesql @query,
                   N'@searchtrtype NVARCHAR(255)',   -- or whatever the right type is
                   @searchtrtype=@searchtrtype;
```

You cannot pass in identifiers, only values, so this doesn't work for `@orderbycondition`.

Comment: Looks like you had the same concern about `@orderbycondition` that i did.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parametrise your SQL. Concatenating string for SQL is an awful idea; as it leaves you open to injection. The way you want to do it would be:

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX);
SET @query =  N'SELECT y.ID,' + NCHAR(10) + 
              N'       y.STATUS,' + NCHAR(10) + 
              N'       y.CONTROLID,' + NCHAR(10) + 
              N'       y.TRCDE' + NCHAR(10) + 
              N'FROM YTDTRNI AS y' + NCHAR(10) + 
              N'     LEFT JOIN VND AS v ON y.COMNO = v.COMNO ' + NCHAR(10) + 
              N'WHERE TRCDE = @dsearchtrtype' + NCHAR(10) + 
              N'ORDER BY ' + QUOTENAME(@orderbycondition) + N';';
PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@dsearchtrtype nvarchar(100)', @dsearchtrtype = @searchtrtype;
```

This, however, probably isn't going to work, due to your variable `@orderbycondition`. I don't know, however, what type of value that has, however, if it's something like `'ID desc'`, this it would become `ORDER BY [ID desc];`.

If this assumption is correct, I would suggest using 2 variables; one for the sort column and one for the direction, and replace the final line of the dynamic SQl with:

```
N'ORDER BY ' + QUOTENAME(@orderbycolumn) + N' ' + CASE WHEN @orderbydirection NOT IN(N'ASC',N'DESC') THEN N'' ELSE @orderbydirection END + N';';
```

If your value of `@orderbycondition` can be more complex than that, post a comment to let me know (and update your question with more detail), and I'll be happy to explain how to create a more dynamic `ORDER BY` clause using a table type parameter, along with adding it to your dynamic SQL with use of `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`.

Comment: I have tried out your method and I am almost there. When I execute the stored procedure it will return the result set that I want but it also shows an error message:  `Must declare the scalar variable "@dsearchtrtype".`

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reference `@dsearchtrtype` outside of the dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example provided it appears that the OP simply wants to filter on a single column and perform a sort on a user specified column. This can be achieved with a parametrized query without the need of dynamic SQL.

Within the where clause the `TRCDE` field can be directly assigned to the `@searchtrtype` parameter. The dynamic sorting requirement is a little trickier but can be achieved by using a `CASE` statement within the `ORDER BY` clause. An additional parameter will have to be included to indicate if the sorting should be ascending or descending. The following query demonstrates:

```
DECLARE @orderByColumn  NVARCHAR(50) = 'ID'; -- The column to sort by
DECLARE @sortAscending BIT = 1; -- Indicate sorting order 1 == Ascending, 0 == Descending
DECLARE @searchtrtype NVARCHAR(10) = 'RC'

IF @sortAscending = 1 -- Sort data in ascending order
BEGIN

    SELECT       y.[ID]
                ,y.[STATUS]
                ,y.[CONTROLID]
                ,y.[TRCDE]
    FROM        YTDTRNI AS y 
    LEFT JOIN   VND AS v ON y.[COMNO] = v.[COMNO]
    WHERE       TRCDE = @searchtrtype 
    ORDER BY    (
                    -- Create case statement for every column user may want to filter on
                    CASE
                        WHEN @orderByColumn = 'ID' THEN [ID]
                        ELSE NULL -- Simply return null if we are not ordering by this column, effectively ignore the column.
                    END
                 ),
                 (
                    CASE
                        WHEN @orderByColumn = 'STATUS' THEN [STATUS]
                        ELSE NULL -- Simply return null if we are not ordering by this column, effectively ignore the column.
                    END
                 ),
                             (
                    CASE
                        WHEN @orderByColumn = 'CONTROLID' THEN [CONTROLID]
                        ELSE NULL -- Simply return null if we are not ordering by this column, effectively ignore the column.
                    END
                 ) ASC;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT       y.[ID]
                ,y.[STATUS]
                ,y.[CONTROLID]
                ,y.[TRCDE]
    FROM        YTDTRNI AS y 
    LEFT JOIN   VND AS v ON y.[COMNO] = v.[COMNO]
    WHERE       TRCDE = @searchtrtype 
    ORDER BY    (
                    CASE
                        WHEN @orderByColumn = 'ID' THEN [ID]
                        ELSE NULL -- Simply return null if we are not ordering by this column, effectively ignore the column.
                    END
                 ),
                 (
                    CASE
                        WHEN @orderByColumn = 'STATUS' THEN [STATUS]
                        ELSE NULL -- Simply return null if we are not ordering by this column, effectively ignore the column.
                    END
                 ),
                             (
                    CASE
                        WHEN @orderByColumn = 'CONTROLID' THEN [CONTROLID]
                        ELSE NULL -- Simply return null if we are not ordering by this column, effectively ignore the column.
                    END
                 ) DESC;
END
```

This method is more work but will be easier to troubleshoot, maintain and will protect you from SQL Injection.

Answer (score -1):

do you just need to include escaped  apostrophes.  if @searchtrtype  can contain apostrophes, you might have to escape them with REPLACE(@searchtrtype, '''', '''''')

```
SET @query =  N'SELECT y.ID, y.STATUS,y.CONTROLID,y.TRCDE
FROM YTDTRNI AS y LEFT JOIN VND AS v ON y.COMNO = v.COMNO 
WHERE TRCDE = ''' + @searchtrtype + ''' 
ORDER BY ' + @orderbycondition
```